# Swift 2.2 HealthKit - Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error not handled

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, swift2

I'm following a health kit tutorial found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86336/ios-8-healthkit-swift-getting-started)

It is using an older version of Swift (1.2) and I am trying to convert it to the latest version (Swift 2.2 as of this writing)

The error indicates that I need to do a `do, catch, and try` handling but, it is still throwing the same error `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error not handled`?

I have added my attempt below. With Swift 2.2 do I still need to check for the error using the latest `if error != nil`? Or would that be handled in the `do, catch, try` handling now?

```
var error:NSError?
var age:Int?

// 1. Request birthday and calculate age
if let birthDay = healthKitStore.dateOfBirth()
{
  do {
    let today = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let differenceComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: birthDay, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0) )

    try! age = differenceComponents.year

  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
}
if error != nil {
  print("Error reading Birthday: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement do try catch Swift2 error handling method when a method throws. You should always handle the errors. If you are sure it will never fail you can use try! and if you dont want to handle the error you can use try?

Try like this:

```
var age: Int?
do {
    // 1. Request birthday and calculate age
    let birthDay = try healthKitStore.dateOfBirth()
    age = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Year, fromDate: birthDay, toDate: NSDate(), options: []).year
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks Leo! Was this that simple of an error to fix? I could not understand the docs for when and where to use the try method (sometimes I see it forced `try!` as well? Is there a good resource to understanding this better?